# Randomized benchmarking: How do we calculate the reversal element of RB sequence?

Tags: clifford-group, random-quantum-circuit, randomised-benchmarking

In randomized benchmarking the random sequences consist of random Clifford elements, including a computed reversal element, that should return the qubits to the initial state.

Let's assume that we know a random sequence of Clifford elements. How do we calculate the reversal element using only gates $X_{\pi/2}$ and $Y_{\pi/2}$ in the case of one qubit?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. What do you mean by $X(\pi/2)$ gate? Based on your question, it seems that it is a Pauli $X$ but why to include the angle...

Comment: It's an operator of rotation around X-axis.

Comment: I don’t know much about this, and may be way off, but why is it really bad just to run in reverse? It just doubles the length, but requires no other computational effort.